# Package works only inside window.onload function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, import, package, node-modules

I installed D3.js with **npm install d3**, so now there are directory node_modules with d3 package. Now in my js file I want use d3, and d3 works only inside **window.onload** function
for ex.:

**UPDATED**

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";

window.onload = function(){
    const sq = d3.selectAll('rect')
        .attr("fill", "red");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vis</title>
    <script src="node_modules/d3/build/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src='build/bundle.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

<svg width="300px" height="150px">
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="20px" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" ></rect>
    <rect x="60" y="20" width="20px" height="20" rx="5" ry="5" ></rect>
    <rect x="100" y="20" width="20px" height="20" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

this is part of my package-lock.json which shows that d3 is installed:

> {
>     "name": "vis",
>     "version": "1.0.0",
>     "lockfileVersion": 1,
>     "requires": true,
>
> > "dependencies": {
> >
> > > "d3": {
> > >             "version": "4.12.2",
> > >             "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/d3/-/d3-4.12.2.tgz",
> > >             "integrity": "sha512-aKAlpgTmpuGeEpezB+GvPpX1x+gCMs/PHpuse6sCpkgw4Un3ZeqUobIc87eIy9adcl+wxPAnEyKyO5oulH3MOw==",
> > >             "requires": {
> > >               "d3-array": "1.2.1",
> > >               "d3-axis": "1.0.8",
> > >               "d3-brush": "1.0.4",
> > >               "d3-chord": "1.0.4",
> > >               "d3-collection": "1.0.4",
> > >               "d3-color": "1.0.3",
> > >               "d3-dispatch": "1.0.3",
> > >               "d3-drag": "1.2.1",
> > >               "d3-dsv": "1.0.8",
> > >               "d3-ease": "1.0.3",
> > >               "d3-force": "1.1.0",
> > >               "d3-format": "1.2.1",
> > >               "d3-geo": "1.9.1",
> > >               "d3-hierarchy": "1.1.5",
> > >               "d3-interpolate": "1.1.6",
> > >               "d3-path": "1.0.5",
> > >               "d3-polygon": "1.0.3",
> > >               "d3-quadtree": "1.0.3",
> > >               "d3-queue": "3.0.7",
> > >               "d3-random": "1.1.0",
> > >               "d3-request": "1.0.6",
> > >               "d3-scale": "1.0.7",
> > >               "d3-selection": "1.2.0",
> > >               "d3-shape": "1.2.0",
> > >               "d3-time": "1.0.8",
> > >               "d3-time-format": "2.1.1",
> > >               "d3-timer": "1.0.7",
> > >               "d3-transition": "1.1.1",
> > >               "d3-voronoi": "1.1.2",
> > >               "d3-zoom": "1.7.1"
> > >             }

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Now you need to import the d3 module using `import` statement or use `require.js` for `AMD` or `common.js` style

Comment: @brk even with import or require it does not work

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know. I am a beginner and tutorials which I saw didn't use that :))

Comment: well the element you want to target has to exist before you do anything to it. If that code is in the `<head>` it would run before elements exist but they do after load event

Comment: Can you place all code

Comment: @Dipakchavda updated code above

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work **probably** because you are using d3 e.g. `d3.selectAll('rect')` to manipulate **elements** that is **not ready** yet. `window.onload` executes callback when all resources have finished loading and are ready to use - that is the reason why there it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <head>
        <script charset="utf-8" src="/node_modules/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <svg width="300px" height="150px">
            <rect x="20" y="20" width="20px" height="20" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
            <rect x="60" y="20" width="20px" height="20" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
            <rect x="100" y="20" width="20px" height="20" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
        </svg>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                const sq = d3.selectAll('rect')
                    .attr("fill", "red");
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```